# function inside useEffect hook is not triggered after state manipulation

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am pretty new to react and I am really confused why a specific useEffect hook in my code isnt triggered although I am updating a previously defined State which was created using useState hook. Hopefully an expert is able to tell me after short review, what is causing this.

The "callbackfn" is updating the state of the function component using the states setter method "setBadgeStates(...)"

```
export default function BadgeGroup() {
  const [badgeStates, setBadgeStates] = useState([
    false,
    false,
    false,
    false,
    false,
    false,
    false,
  ]);

  const useIsMount = () => {
    const isMountRef = useRef(true);
    useEffect(() => {
      isMountRef.current = false;
    }, []);
    return isMountRef.current;
  };
  const isMount = useIsMount();

**  useEffect(() => {
    if (isMount) {
    } else {
      console.log(badgeStates);
    }
  }, [badgeStates]);**

  const callbackfn = (value) => {
    if (value[0] === true) {
      console.log(value);
      let states = badgeStates;
      states[value[1]] = true;
      **setBadgeStates(states);**
    } else {
      console.log(value);
    }
  };
```

I was googeling a for some hours and I also tried asking ChatGPT which wasnt very useful.

Comment: You are not updating state (`setBadgeStates`) in *immutable* way; also it seems you defined the custom hook inside your component, not sure if that is a good idea, best move it out.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I just got to this solution by myself. If somebody needs to know how to update an array item in react state use this link:
https://react.dev/learn/updating-arrays-in-state#replacing-items-in-an-array

Answer (score 0):

You should treat arrays in React state as read-only. Check below example, How reference type works in javascript

[image]

The solution to your problem

```
  const callbackfn = (value) => {
    if (value[0] === true) {
      console.log(value);
      let states = [...badgeStates];//new copy of exising array
      states[value[1]] = true;
      setBadgeStates(states);
    } else {
      console.log(value);
    }
  };
```